# Is there a more efficient way to write this custom SQL in Django based on a conditional number of arguments?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, database-cursor

I'm fairly new to SQL and Django and am trying to use custom SQL statements for an app I'm building in Django. The reason I am opting to not use the ORM is to compare performance and to see if I can get it working before taking the time to translate and switch over.

Anyways, the application takes a bunch of user defined "filters" such as date range (2 weeks, 1 month, custom range), and a checklist of job types, and spits out the results from the search.

So for instance, I made a simplified query along the lines of something I am doing below. Looking at the statement below as an example, I would need to replace each string ('office', 'teacher', '2019-07-01', etc.) with an %s and then pass in parameters. I am planning to build a conditional parameter list to just pass in for the various arguments in python.

Query from MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM joblist 
WHERE (job = 'office' OR job = 'teacher' OR job = 'student')
AND date > '2019-07-01' AND date < '2019-07-15';
```

Becomes this in Django

```
sql_statement = '''SELECT * FROM joblist 
WHERE (job = %s OR job = %s OR job = %s)
AND date > %s AND date < %s;'''
...
```

```py
...
cursor.execute(sql_statement, [params])
```

My question is how do I fill in the WHERE field part of the statement if i don't know how many %s or parameters I need in the first place? It could vary and have 2 job parameters or 1 job parameter based on how many boxes the user has checked.

I know I can do a bunch of if elif statements and repeatedly account for each combination of possible user searches, but there has to be a way better way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you have a model somewhere?

Comment: This is actually one of the *many* reasons to use the ORM (together with security, elegance, simplicity, etc.) :)

Comment: well currently the sql query I have is optimized to run very quickly, whereas the orm method is taking a long time to run, so I just want to get it to work this way first before i spend the time going back to translate everything in greater detail. From looking at the documentation, custom SQL does not utilize the models layer at all. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: but the model layer just constructs a query. Usually this runs at the Python level, and takes little to no time compared to executing the query. Furthermore the ORM will, especially for simple cases like this one, come up with the same query like the one you constructed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the example i provided is a major simplification of the actual query i'm running, which has gigs of data. i know i can use the orm approach and i agree with you advocating for it because that's one of the selling points of django but right now i wish to get it working using custom sql to understand how it works before i do it the "django way". any ideas?

Comment: but you can just use `print(MyModel.object.filter().query)` what Django constructed as query. In this case, you could query with something like `Job.objects.filter(job__in=['office', 'teacher', 'student'], date__range=['2019-07-02', '2019-07-14'])`. It would result in a query `SELECT * FROM job WHERE job IN ('office', 'teacher', 'student') AND date BETWEEN 2019-07-02 AND 2019-07-04`. Not only is it more convenient, usually an `col IN (val1,val2)` and `some_date BETWEEN ... AND ...` are faster than the `... OR ...` and range checks at database side.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Django you can use the `__in` filter instead of repeated IFs for the same column

```
job_names = ('office', 'teacher', 'student')
Job.objects.filter(
    job__in=job_names,
    date__range=(date_from, date_to)
)
```